# Flipping a flag in a Collection

Tags: java, java-8

We have a List of **eligible** Students - `List<Student>`.

```
Student {

    String name;
    ..........
    ..........
    Status status = Status.NONE;

}
```

We need to set the default of all eligible students as `STATUS.PASSED`
Does Java 8 have a better/shorter option than the `for(student in students)` loop?

Comment: What's wrong with `for(Student s : students)`, Just use it. Java8 does not provide any better alternative.

Comment: @Naman et al. If you find a good duplicate for this question, I'm all for closing in favor of the duplicate, but the duplicate that is currently there does not address the question at all. Nowhere in the question is there any mention of conditions or filtering.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Agree with you, and didn't flag it as a duplicate too.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen My bad to have missed the details. Thanks for calling that out. I hope the updated links address the current question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach` for that:

```
students.forEach(s -> s.setStatus(STATUS.PASSED));
```

And if it's conditional, then:

```
students.stream()
    .filter(s -> hasPassed(s))
    .forEach(s -> s.setStatus(STATUS.PASSED));
```

Or even shorter:

```
students.forEach(s -> s.setStatus(hasPassed(s) ? STATUS.PASSED : Status.NONE));
```

Answer (score 1):

For a shorter implementation, you can use `forEach()`:

```
students.forEach(s -> s.status = Status.PASSED);
```

For a more performant implementation, a traditional `for` loop might shave off a couple of milliseconds, depending on compiler/runtime optimizations:

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
    students.get(i).status = Status.PASSED;
}
```

Comment: there is an event need to be passed, before making the flag to `Status.PASSED`

Comment: @VishwaRatna What event? The question provides no details about any event; it just says "[a]fter an event, we need to set ...". Or did you mean a condition instead of an event? Or an argument? Nothing in the question about a condition or argument either...

Comment: **After an *event*,we need to set the default of all eligible students as STATUS.PASSED** Passing event is the part of solution, isn't it?

Comment: @VishwaRatna "We have a list of eligible students. After an event, we need to set the default of **all** eligible students..."

Comment: If you don't use condition then you will end up setting the flag to `status.passed` to **non eligible students** also, so there you must have a condition check.

Comment: @VishwaRatna The questions begins by stating that the list is *already* a list of eligible students.

Comment: got it from **We have a List of eligible Students - List<Student>**